# Spyder is not updated after updating anaconda

Tags: anaconda, spyder

i use commands to update anaconda.

```
 conda update conda
 conda update anaconda
```

when it succeed,i found Spyder is still in old version.

so,what the command `conda update anaconda` actually do?

Comment: What is *the old version*?